# How to copy text to clipboard in visual mode?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I ran the following sequence of commands:

> `V10j` <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>

but it seems like this doesn't copy the ten lines to my clipboard. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim uses registers to store text.  It may be helpful for you to read `:h registers` if you haven't already, as well as the user manual (this is covered in [section 04.7](https://vimhelp.org/usr_04.txt.html#04.7))

Assuming you are using a version with the clipboard feature compiled in (which the default vim version on macOS as well as homebrew has), you can use the `*` register.  So for your visual mode selection you would do:

```
V10j"*y
```

Note that this can also be achieved in normal mode without entering visual mode by doing `"*y10j`.

Comment: What does `"` do here?

Comment: The `"` is like: "select this register" (in fact you can choose the a, b, c, d, etc. register to copy your text)